# Affablebean ошибка

Tags: java-ee

Здравствуйте. Изучаю Java EE на примере приложения Affablebean в NetBeans. Может кто сталкивался с этой ошибкой и знает как исправить?
Создаю классы сущностей из базы данных, потом сеансовые компоненты для сущностных классов.При этом генерируется persistence.xml. В сервлете переопределяю init()

```
@EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
       getServletContext().setAttribute("categories", categoryFacade.findAll());
    }
```

запускаю приложение и вылетает ошибка

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/affablebean"

Подозреваю что-то не так с persistence.xml

Comment: как вы запускаете приложение?

Comment: Нормально запускаю на разных этапах создания приложения. После описанного мною выше приложение не запускается.

Comment: это не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: В ide запускаю.

Comment: опишите подробно как вы это делаете. какой сервер используете. Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: Я рассчитывал на ответы тех, кто проходил этот "туториал" и сталкивался с данной ошибкой. Там используется GlassFish. Спасибо, конечно, за участие.

Comment: тогда в вопросе стоило это указать. И дать ссылку на руководство. Ошибка скорее всего в не правильных настройках сервера.

Comment: OK попробую с Tomcat в Eclipse. Что касается ссылки на руководство,думаю всем, кто изучал Java EE известно это руководство :-)

Comment: я изучал - мне не известно. Tomcat вам не подходит. так ссылку добавите?

Comment: NetBeans E-commerce Tutorials https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html

Comment: а почему вы выбрали столь старое руководство?

Comment: Потому что не видел новых руководств по Java EE.

Comment: чем вот это плохо https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ ?

Comment: Тем, что AffableBean это реальный рабочий проект, со всеми прибамбасами. А по вашей ссылке там маленькие примерчики сугубо для обучения. И это у меня тоже в процессе изучения.

Comment: думаете за 7 лет тенденции не поменялись? :) там используется java 6, а сейчас уже 9 на подходе.

Comment: Это единственный реальный пример создания интернет магазина на Java EE который я нашел. Есть еще примеры в комплекте NetBeans, но там только код без туториала. Поэтому я решил начать с этого. По крайней мере будет понимание как это делалось несколько лет назад.